# Constants in Model and View with select option and show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some values which I use in my model as constants:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base    
    LEGS = {:vierbeiner => 4, :zweibeiner => 2 }
end
```

In the form (formtastic) for the collection i use:

```
<%= f.input :legs, :as => :select, :collection => Animal::LEGS =>
```

How do I format the view so that instead of showing me the number , it shows the key of the hash?

In show view I have:

```
<p><strong>Legs:</strong><%=h @animal.legs %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal::LEGS.select{ |k,v| v == @animal.legs }.first.first
```

Though better make it a helper.